# Opening hyperlinks stops working when browser runs in sandbox (firejail)

Tags: org-link, hyperlinks, web-browser

Opening links (e.g. [[https://www.example.com][example]]) stops working when browser (librewolf) runs in a sandbox (firejail). The only output it gives is "nil". It works again when sandbox is removed.

I've tried removing all sandbox features from the browser (dbus, blacklisted paths) and it still doesn't open links. Other programs (terminal, GUI file manager, xdg-open) are still able to open links just fine.

I've tried debugging org-open-at-point function, but it didn't help.

If anyone has any ideas what may be causing it that would be really helpful.

Comment: what is 'org-file-apps' set to?

Comment: It's ```((remote . emacs)
 (auto-mode . emacs)
 (directory . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))
``` On the system Librewolf is the default web browser.